# OpenGL/GLFW - scroll wheel not responding

Tags: c++, opengl

I am following along with [this tutorial series](https://learnopengl.com/#!Introduction), but also trying to customise my solution as I go along (essentially I am trying to render a 3D point cloud -ie. a whole bunch of XYZ points).

I have been able to get the camera working and a 3D environment going. I am happy to work on the rest of that by myself, but the problem I am having is that the scroll wheel is not responding. I am hoping this is blindingly obvious to someone. It seems that the only user callback the program is getting is that of the mouse position - 100% of the time - and that's preventing the scroll_callback function form being heard. Can someone explain why my scroll wheel callback is not being received. Code below.

Let me know if any further info is required.

I am using Visual Studio 2017 Community.

```
#include <glad/glad.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/type_ptr.hpp>

#include <Shader.h>

#include <iostream>


void framebuffer_size_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int width, int height);
void mouse_callback(GLFWwindow* window, double xpos, double ypos);
void scroll_callback(GLFWwindow* window, double xoffset, double yoffset);
void processInput(GLFWwindow *window);

// settings
const unsigned int SCR_WIDTH = 800;
const unsigned int SCR_HEIGHT = 800;

// camera
glm::vec3 cameraPos = glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 3.0f);
glm::vec3 cameraFront = glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f);
glm::vec3 cameraUp = glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

bool firstMouse = true;
float yaw = -90.0f; // yaw is initialized to -90.0 degrees since a yaw of 0.0 results in a direction vector pointing to the right so we initially rotate a bit to the left.
float pitch = 0.0f;
float lastX = 800.0f / 2.0;
float lastY = 600.0 / 2.0;
float fov = 45.0f;

// timing
float deltaTime = 0.0f; // time between current frame and last frame
float lastFrame = 0.0f;


int main()
{
    // glfw: initialize and configure
    // ------------------------------
    glfwInit();
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    //glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE); // uncomment this statement to fix compilation on OS X

    // glfw window creation
    // --------------------
    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(SCR_WIDTH, SCR_HEIGHT, "LearnOpenGL", NULL, NULL);
    if (window == NULL)
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to create GLFW window" << std::endl;
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback(window, framebuffer_size_callback);
    glfwSetCursorPosCallback(window, mouse_callback);
    glfwSetScrollCallback(window, scroll_callback);

    // tell GLFW to capture our mouse
    glfwSetInputMode(window, GLFW_CURSOR, GLFW_CURSOR_NORMAL);

    // glad: load all OpenGL function pointers
    // ---------------------------------------
    if (!gladLoadGLLoader((GLADloadproc)glfwGetProcAddress))
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to initialize GLAD" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }


    // configure global opengl state
    // -----------------------------
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    Shader ourShader("VertexShader.vs", "FragShader.fs");




// set up vertex data (and buffer(s)) and configure vertex attributes
// ------------------------------------------------------------------
float vertices[] = {
    -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, // left  
    0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, // right 
    0.0f,  0.5f, 0.0f  // top   
};

struct Point
{
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
};

Point points[500];


for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
{
    points[i].x = (float)((rand() % SCR_WIDTH) + 1);
    points[i].y = (float)((rand() % SCR_WIDTH) + 1);
    points[i].z = (float)((rand() % SCR_WIDTH) + 1);

    // X Coords to Normalised Device coordinates
    if (points[i].x > 400)
    {
        points[i].x = points[i].x * 0.00125f;
    }
    else if (points[i].x < 400)
    {
        points[i].x = points[i].x * -0.00125f;
    }
    else if (points[i].x == 400)
    {
        points[i].x = 0.0f;
    }

    // Y Coords to Normalised Device coordinates
    if (points[i].y > 400)
    {
        points[i].y = points[i].y * 0.00125f;
    }
    else if (points[i].y < 400)
    {
        points[i].y = points[i].y * -0.00125f;
    }
    else if (points[i].y == 400)
    {
        points[i].y = 0.0f;
    }

    // Z Coords to Normalised Device coordinates
    if (points[i].z > 400)
    {
        points[i].z = points[i].z * 0.00125f;
    }
    else if (points[i].z < 400)
    {
        points[i].z = points[i].z * -0.00125f;
    }
    else if (points[i].z == 400)
    {
        points[i].z = 0.0f;
    }

    //cout << points[i].x << ", " << points[i].y << ", " << points[i].z << endl;
}

unsigned int VBO, VAO;
glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
// bind the Vertex Array Object first, then bind and set vertex buffer(s), and then configure vertex attributes(s).
glBindVertexArray(VAO);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(points), points, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

// note that this is allowed, the call to glVertexAttribPointer registered VBO as the vertex attribute's bound vertex buffer object so afterwards we can safely unbind
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

// You can unbind the VAO afterwards so other VAO calls won't accidentally modify this VAO, but this rarely happens. Modifying other
// VAOs requires a call to glBindVertexArray anyways so we generally don't unbind VAOs (nor VBOs) when it's not directly necessary.
glBindVertexArray(0);


// uncomment this call to draw in wireframe polygons.
//glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE);

// render loop
// -----------
while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
{
    // input
    // -----
    processInput(window);

    // render
    // ------
    glClearColor(0.2f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    // activate shader
    ourShader.use();

    // create transformations
    glm::mat4 projection;
    projection = glm::perspective(glm::radians(95.0f), (float)SCR_WIDTH / (float)SCR_HEIGHT, 0.1f, 100.0f);
    ourShader.setMat4("projection", projection); // note: currently we set the projection matrix each frame, but since the projection matrix rarely changes it's often best practice to set it outside the main loop only once.

    // camera/view transformation
    glm::mat4 view = glm::lookAt(cameraPos, cameraPos + cameraFront, cameraUp);
    ourShader.setMat4("view", view);

    glm::mat4 model;
    model = glm::rotate(model, glm::radians(-55.0f), glm::vec3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
    ourShader.setMat4("model", model);


    // draw our points array
    //glUseProgram(shaderProgram);
    glBindVertexArray(VAO); // seeing as we only have a single VAO there's no need to bind it every time, but we'll do so to keep things a bit more organized
    glPointSize(3.0f);
    glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, 500);
    // glBindVertexArray(0); // no need to unbind it every time 

    // glfw: swap buffers and poll IO events (keys pressed/released, mouse moved etc.)
    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    glfwPollEvents();
}

// optional: de-allocate all resources once they've outlived their purpose:
// ------------------------------------------------------------------------
glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
glDeleteBuffers(1, &VBO);

// glfw: terminate, clearing all previously allocated GLFW resources.
// ------------------------------------------------------------------
glfwTerminate();
return 0;
}

// process all input: query GLFW whether relevant keys are pressed/released this frame and react accordingly
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void processInput(GLFWwindow *window)
{
    if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE) == GLFW_PRESS)
        glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, true);

    float cameraSpeed = 2.5 * deltaTime;
    if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_W) == GLFW_PRESS)
        cameraPos += cameraSpeed * cameraFront;
    if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_S) == GLFW_PRESS)
        cameraPos -= cameraSpeed * cameraFront;
    if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_A) == GLFW_PRESS)
        cameraPos -= glm::normalize(glm::cross(cameraFront, cameraUp)) * cameraSpeed;
    if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_D) == GLFW_PRESS)
        cameraPos += glm::normalize(glm::cross(cameraFront, cameraUp)) * cameraSpeed;
}

// glfw: whenever the window size changed (by OS or user resize) this callback function executes
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void framebuffer_size_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int width, int height)
{
    // make sure the viewport matches the new window dimensions; note that width and 
    // height will be significantly larger than specified on retina displays.
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
}

// glfw: whenever the mouse moves, this callback is called
// -------------------------------------------------------
void mouse_callback(GLFWwindow* window, double xpos, double ypos)
{
    if (firstMouse)
    {
        lastX = xpos;
        lastY = ypos;
        firstMouse = false;
    }

    float xoffset = xpos - lastX;
    float yoffset = lastY - ypos; // reversed since y-coordinates go from bottom to top
    lastX = xpos;
    lastY = ypos;

    float sensitivity = 0.1f; // change this value to your liking
    xoffset *= sensitivity;
    yoffset *= sensitivity;

    yaw += xoffset;
    pitch += yoffset;

    // make sure that when pitch is out of bounds, screen doesn't get flipped
    if (pitch > 89.0f)
        pitch = 89.0f;
    if (pitch < -89.0f)
        pitch = -89.0f;

    glm::vec3 front;
    front.x = cos(glm::radians(yaw)) * cos(glm::radians(pitch));
    front.y = sin(glm::radians(pitch));
    front.z = sin(glm::radians(yaw)) * cos(glm::radians(pitch));
    cameraFront = glm::normalize(front);
}

// glfw: whenever the mouse scroll wheel scrolls, this callback is called
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------
void scroll_callback(GLFWwindow* window, double xoffset, double yoffset)
{
    if (fov >= 1.0f && fov <= 45.0f)
        fov -= yoffset;
    if (fov <= 1.0f)
        fov = 1.0f;
    if (fov >= 45.0f)
        fov = 45.0f;
}
```

Comment: That would be a GLFW problem rather than an OpenGL problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're going to facepalm a little:

```
projection = glm::perspective(glm::radians(95.0f), (float)SCR_WIDTH / (float)SCR_HEIGHT, 0.1f, 100.0f);
```

should be:

```
projection = glm::perspective(glm::radians(fov), (float)SCR_WIDTH / (float)SCR_HEIGHT, 0.1f, 100.0f);
```

I ran your code in a debugger and the scroll callback function is running every time but the `fov` value was never being used. You can use the same technique if you ever want to check if a function is being called by adding a break point anywhere in the function.

Comment: **epic facepalm**